# Changing months into days in moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm using [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment) to format dates on my website. I'm displaying relative dates (6 hours ago, 2 months ago) instead of absolute dates (16 October 2013).

Instead of using months (2 months ago, 7 months ago), my aim is to display days (60 days ago, 210 days ago etc).

I've looked through moment.js and suspect I should modify `diff :` but I'm not sure what to change or if this is the right place. See here:

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js#L1997

Hoping for some help on how can I modify moment.js to display days instead of months by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.diff()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) like this:

```
moment().diff('2014-05-10', 'days'); // 3
```

You can extend moment to get a `diffInDays` function if you'd like:

```
moment.fn.diffInDays = function(m) {
  return this.diff(m, 'days');
}
```

Then you can do like:

```
moment().diffInDays(moment('2014-05-10'));
```

or even just:

```
moment().diffInDays('2014-05-10');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll use that for sure but what I'm looking for in this case is a way to ensure the number of 'days' is displayed by default in place of the number of 'months'. i.e. i think it will involve modifying moment.js

Comment: I would recommend against modifying `moment.js`. Why not build your own function to call if you want to do this? It could work like: `function timeAgoInDays (since) { return moment().diff(since, 'days'); }` where `since` is a `moment`.